# Get the value of a field of the taxonomy term referenced with an Entity Reference field

Tags: users, entities, chaos-tool-suite

I have a taxonomy vocabulary "Partners", with boolean field `field_1`. When I create a user, I attach to it a term from the vocabulary "Partners" with an Entity Reference field. Is there a way to get the value of the `field_1` field of that term and to bind it to the user?

(In the first case I need this value to limit the access to a page created by Page Manager to the users whose partners has the `field_1` field filled with the value `1`. I suppose I need the field value also for other cases later.)

The relation of the user and the partner could be made in another way, too, if it will be easier, more intuitive or more practical.

Answer (score 0):

The user is already associated with the boolean field via the taxonomy term.

For example, load your user's account:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
```

Now load your taxonomy term:

```
$partner = taxonomy_term_load($account->taxonomy_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']);
```

And then get the boolean value of field_1:

```
$boolean_value = $partner->field_1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

Comment: Thank you. As I am not a programmer, I'm not sure if I manage to handle this, but I'll try.